# Find the value of $z_1^2 +z_2^2$?

Tags: complex-numbers

$z_1,z_2$ belongs to $\Bbb C$ (Complex Numbers)

We are given that $z_1(z_1^2-3z_2^2) = 2$ and $z_2(3z_1^2-z_2^2)=1$

If $z_1^2+z_2^2$ belongs to real numbers, then find the value of $z_1^2+z_2^2$?

I tried to use the algebraic identities or taking $z_1 z_2$ to right hand side and subtracting the equations to get the $z_1^2 + z_2^2$ term but to no avail.

Is there a better approach to solve this question?

Comment: Multiply the second equation by $\pm i$ and add it to the first equation. You get that $(z_1\pm iz_2)^3=1\pm i$. Then multiply those two equation. to get that $(z_1^2+z_2^2)^3=2$. Since $z_1^2+z_2^2$ is real, it must be $\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: @plop Thanks for your comment. This approach is really great.

Comment: But I think there is a typo in “1 ± i“, it should be “2 ±i”.

Comment: And thus answer 5^1/3

Comment: @plop But anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes. I misread it as both expression being equal to $1$.